# Find maximum value from JSON objects from array and Merge them

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js, lodash

I am new to javascript and  I have JSON array that contains some duplicate keys like below:

```
var connections = [

  {
      "source":"l1",
      "target":"l2",
      "metrics": { "normal":20  },
      "metadata": { "streaming": 1 }
    },
   {
      "source":"l2",
      "target":"l3",
      "metrics": { "normal":30  },
      "metadata": { "streaming": 1 }
    },

    {
      "source":"l2",
      "target":"l3",
      "metrics": { "normal":25  },
      "metadata": { "streaming": 1 }
    },
    {
      "source":"l3",
      "target":"l4",
      "metrics": { "normal":24  },
      "metadata": { "streaming": 1 }
    },
    {
      "source":"l3",
      "target":"l4",
      "metrics": { "normal":21  },
      "metadata": { "streaming": 1 }
    },
    {
      "source":"l3",
      "target":"l4",
      "metrics": { "normal":20  },
      "metadata": { "streaming": 1 }
    },


]
```

Now I want to merge duplicate JSON who has same value of "source" and "target" and key "normal" should be maximum of all same source and target.
So the answer for given example will be:

```
var answer =[
{
          "source":"l1",
          "target":"l2",
          "metrics": { "normal":20  },
          "metadata": { "streaming": 1 }
        },
       {
          "source":"l2",
          "target":"l3",
          "metrics": { "normal":30  },
          "metadata": { "streaming": 1 }
        },
        {
          "source":"l3",
          "target":"l4",
          "metrics": { "normal":24  },
          "metadata": { "streaming": 1 }
        },

]
```

This is just an example object it goes on with different objects. I don't know how to solve this problem,
I think underscore or lodash can be easy to solve this problem but any knid of solution is accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_.groupBy()` to collect objects by their source and target. Use `_.map()` and Array#reduce to get the one with the maximum `normal` value in each group.

```js
var connections = [{"source":"l1","target":"l2","metrics":{"normal":20},"metadata":{"streaming":1}},{"source":"l2","target":"l3","metrics":{"normal":30},"metadata":{"streaming":1}},{"source":"l2","target":"l3","metrics":{"normal":25},"metadata":{"streaming":1}},{"source":"l3","target":"l4","metrics":{"normal":24},"metadata":{"streaming":1}},{"source":"l3","target":"l4","metrics":{"normal":21},"metadata":{"streaming":1}},{"source":"l3","target":"l4","metrics":{"normal":20},"metadata":{"streaming":1}}];

var result = _(connections)
  .groupBy(function(o) { // group by source and target
    return o.source + '-' + o.target;
  })
  .map(function(arr) { // map the groups to values
    return arr.reduce(function(max, o) { // get the object with the hight normal in each group
      return max.metrics.normal > o.metrics.normal ? max : o;
    });
  })
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object as a map, having the `source` + `target` as keys and the object of `connections` as value, keeping the ones with highest metrics for each combination of `source` + `target`:

```js
var connections = [
  {"source": "l1", "target": "l2", "metrics": {"normal": 20}, "metadata": {"streaming": 1} }, 
  {"source": "l2", "target": "l3", "metrics": {"normal": 30}, "metadata": {"streaming": 1} },
  {"source": "l2", "target": "l3", "metrics": {"normal": 25}, "metadata": {"streaming": 1} }, 
  {"source": "l3", "target": "l4", "metrics": {"normal": 24}, "metadata": {"streaming": 1} }, 
  {"source": "l3", "target": "l4", "metrics": {"normal": 21}, "metadata": {"streaming": 1} }, 
  {"source": "l3", "target": "l4", "metrics": {"normal": 20}, "metadata": {"streaming": 1} }
];

var map = {};
connections.forEach((connection) => {
  var mapKey = connection.source + "/" + connection.target;
  answerConnection = map[mapKey];

  if (!answerConnection || answerConnection.metrics.normal < connection.metrics.normal)
     map[mapKey] = connection;
});

var answer = Object.values(map);

console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array to a new array based on the target and the source being the same, and then checking if metrics is more than the previously stored value

```js
var connections = [
  {"source": "l1", "target": "l2", "metrics": {"normal": 20}, "metadata": {"streaming": 1} }, 
  {"source": "l2", "target": "l3", "metrics": {"normal": 30}, "metadata": {"streaming": 1} },
  {"source": "l2", "target": "l3", "metrics": {"normal": 25}, "metadata": {"streaming": 1} }, 
  {"source": "l3", "target": "l4", "metrics": {"normal": 24}, "metadata": {"streaming": 1} }, 
  {"source": "l3", "target": "l4", "metrics": {"normal": 21}, "metadata": {"streaming": 1} }, 
  {"source": "l3", "target": "l4", "metrics": {"normal": 20}, "metadata": {"streaming": 1} }
]

var res = connections.reduce( (a,b) => {
    let i = a.findIndex( item => item.target === b.target && item.source === b.source);
    if (i===-1) {
        a.push(b);
    } else if (a[i].metrics.normal < b.metrics.normal) {
        a[i] = b;
    }
    return a;
}, []);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res,0,4) + '</pre>'
```